# MySQL operator IN () only this values

Tags: php, mysql

quite a few hours struggling with a problem, it's more about the issue.

Depicting the script when you type in textboxa searches in SQL data records where name = contain. Assuming that I entered 2 names separated by a comma (X, Y) 2:

a) If you choose "all containing typed values" is to look for all the records,  **in the above "name".** It works:

```
 $where. = "AND  name IN ('". implode (' ', ' ', $array). "')";
```

Model: Contains X. 
Contains The Y; 
Contains the Y and X;

It works as it should.

(b)) If you choose "all containing  **only**  the values to be entered to look for records in which only occurs in the" name "is what we have.

Here I do not know how to do it.

Model: contains the X and Y-only, I don't want records that contain only X, but Y and Alternatively, if in MySQL "name" is 3 options (X, Y, Z).

I do not know how to explain more clearly:--------------------example: I have 5 values in the table, where the name is in different combinations: 
1) Name1, Name2,
 2) name1, Name8,
 3) name1, Name9, 
4) Name8, Name3,
 5) Name4, Name5,
 using the selected the first option, where the textbox typed: "Name1, Name" the result will be: 1), 2), 3), 4), this is valid.

Using the second result should only be 2).

The result of a) res1 or res2 or res1 and res2.
Now I need somehow to come to a solution, when I type in textbox "res1, res2" the result will be: only the records that contain **res1 and res2,** and NOTHING AFTER that.

---- EDIT FOR REPLIES:

```
+--------------------- my_val_search -----------+
| aid | int(11)     | primary key auto_increment|
|name | varchar(255)|               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Records:

```
1|Ruby
2|CSS
3|HTML
4|PHP
5|Python
6|SQL
7|Javascript
8|C++
9|AJAX
10|Java

+---------------------- topics -----------------+
|id      | int(11) | Primary key auto_increment |
|dateline| date    |                            |
 |author  | varchar(30) |                        |
|message | text    |                            |
|aid     |int(11) |foreign key with my_val_search|
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Now if you type in the search "Ruby, Python" I want to have found records only for topics where are "Ruby and Python".

By using the

```
$myValInput = $_GET['keywords'];
$where = "AND a.name IN('" . implode("','", $myValInput. "')";
```

Searches for records, where when you type "Python, Ruby" is divided into:
-Python
-Ruby,
- Python and Ruby 
and I want to make the results appear only for "Python and Ruby". In addition, if someone types "Python, Ruby, Java," the result should be
-Python, Ruby, Java,
 the record should be just what I wrote, nothing more.

Comment: I don't understand anything of what you are saying. Please give your sample data in table format (with column names), specify exactly what you have in `$array` (in PHP syntax), what you get as output, and how that differs from the desired output.

Comment: How could one column contain both values? I don't think this is possible with the given layout

Comment: edited the question. Have a look. @NicoHaase  .

Comment: You can't use IN for AND-ing values - `IN` is for testing if something is _in_ a set. You'll have to spell it out explicitly.

Comment: Based on the `topics` table structure, you can't have more than one `aid` per topic, so how are you linking a topic to both Python and Ruby?

Comment: @MatsLindh So how should I do this?

Comment: Generate separate JOIN statements for each term. However, this assumes that you have an actual many to many relation, since that's not clear from your example tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IN cannot get what you expect!

> When used with a subquery, the word IN is an alias for = ANY. Thus, these two statements are the same:
>
> ```
> SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 = ANY (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
> SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 IN    (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
> ```
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Besides, I think your schema is incorrect. The topic should be `parent` and the topic keywords should be `child`. If I were you, I will do it like this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topic` (
  `id`        int(10) unsigned   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateline`  date,
  `author`    varchar(30),
  `message`   text,

  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topic_keywords` (
  `topic`     int(10) unsigned   NOT NULL,
  `keyword`   varchar(255),

  FOREIGN KEY (`topic`) REFERENCES `topic` (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX (`topic`, `keyword`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In your case, I think the full text is suitable.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topic` (
  `id`        int(10) unsigned   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateline`  date,
  `author`    varchar(30),
  `message`   text,
  `keywords`  varchar(255),

  PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
  FULLTEXT (`keywords`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

```sql
INSERT INTO `topic` (`keywords`)
VALUES ('Ruby,Python'),
       ('Ruby'),
       ('Ruby,SQL'),
       ('Python'),
       ('Python,SQL'),
       ('Ruby,Python,SQL,AJAX');
```

```sql
SELECT `keywords`
  FROM `topic`
 WHERE MATCH(`keywords`) AGAINST('+Ruby +Python' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----------------------+
| keywords             |
+----------------------+
| Ruby,Python          |
| Ruby,Python,SQL,AJAX |
+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

If you just find out the records just exact your input. You can add a hash column. Like design a hash table for your Mysql table. So you can use hash value in your query statement. But don't forget to update the hash value, if your `keywords` value had been changed. Add the before update trigger might be a good choice.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topic` (
  `id`        int(10) unsigned   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateline`  date,
  `author`    varchar(30),
  `message`   text,
  `keywords`  varchar(255),
  `keywords_hash`  varchar(32),

  PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
  FULLTEXT (`keywords`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

```sql
INSERT INTO `topic` 
       (`keywords`   , `keywords_hash`)
VALUES ('Ruby,Python', md5('Ruby,Python'));
```

```sql
SELECT `keywords`
  FROM `topic`
 WHERE `keywords_hash` = md5('Ruby,Python');
```

Comment: HI! 
Is it possible to get the same effect without using FULL-TEXT?

Comment: Using the full-text might be the best way for the case, besides others way will make mysql execute full table scan. Because of the `keywords` column was used as the searchable column.

Comment: IF YOU DON'T CARE THE PERFORMANCE, you have a lot of purposes, like storing keywords with JSON data format and use JSON_SEARCH() function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) -OR- storing keywords as a string split with comma and using FIND_IN_SET() to check the value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at a solution, but there's better solutions query wise than using a regular denormalized structure to handle this - so if you're going to query this a lot (and with a large number of terms), you might want to look into caching the lookup values in your original table and then querying by their content. Anyway, to solve it with regular joins:

Given data:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id int);
CREATE TABLE foo_bar (foo_id int, bar_id int);
CREATE TABLE bar (id int, name varchar(25));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
INSERT INTO bar VALUES (1, 'Ruby'), (2, 'Python'), (3, 'PHP');
INSERT INTO foo_bar VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 3), (2,2);
```

You can retrieve id values from `foo` that has both Ruby and Python by joining each term manually:

```
SELECT f.id FROM foo f 
JOIN foo_bar fb ON fb.foo_id = f.id
JOIN bar b ON fb.bar_id = b.id AND b.name = 'Ruby' 
JOIN foo_bar fb2 ON fb2.foo_id = f.id
JOIN bar b2 ON fb2.bar_id = b2.id AND b2.name = 'Python'
```

This gives `2` as the only id that haves all languages present.